# CSSで、画像を横並び＆重ならない＆ディスプレイサイズに合わせて縮小したい。

Tags: javascript, html, css

### 聞きたいこと

画像を横並びで表示し、かつ、ディスプレイサイズに合わせて縮小する方法。
html,css,javascript関連です。

### 現状と理想

現状）画像を横並びで表示し、かつ、ディスプレイサイズに合わせて縮小しているが、重なってしまっている。
理想）画像を横並びで表示し、かつ、ディスプレイサイズに合わせて縮小しているが、重ならないようにしたい。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 背景

2枚の画像から、正解を選ぶクイズwebアプリを作成しようとしています。
画像の表示方法にてこずっております。

### コード

#### HTML

```
<div class="flex">
      <div id="left">aaa</div>
      <div id="right">aaa</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.flex {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.flex div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

#### Javascript　※不要かもしれませんが一応。

```
// 問題文をランダムに作成。

let imageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
let molfQuestionName = molfArray[imageNumber];
let questionElement = document.getElementById("question-molf-name");
questionElement.innerText = molfQuestionName;

// 正解のモルフを用意する。

let imageElement = document.getElementById("left");
let imageMolf = '<img src="image/' + molfQuestionName + '.jpg">';
// imageElement.innerHTML = imageMolf;

// 不正解のモルフを用意する。

do {
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
} while (i === imageNumber);
let notImageNumber = i;
let notImageElement = document.getElementById("right");
let notImageMolf = '<img src="image/' + molfArray[notImageNumber] + '.jpg">';
// notImageElement.innerHTML = notImageMolf;

// 正解と不正解を格納した配列を用意する。

let optionArray = [];
optionArray[0] = imageMolf;
optionArray[1] = notImageMolf;

// 正解と不正解をランダムにエレメントに格納する。

c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
do {
  d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
} while (c === d);

a = c;
b = d;

imageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[a];
notImageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[b];
```

### 備考

本業はbiz側で、非エンジニアです。
初質問になるため、その他回答に必要な情報がございましたらお申し付けください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この問題は読み込んでいる画像のサイズが大きく、**横並びにしている `div` 要素から画像がはみ出してしまっている**ことが原因です。`div` 要素 (`#left`, `#right`) へ横幅を指定していても、その子要素にあたる `img` 要素には横幅の制約は適用されません。

つまり、 **`img` 要素に対して横幅の制約を加える**ことでこの問題を解決することが出来ます。今回の場合は、親要素以上の横幅にはなってはいけないため、最大横幅を設定する [`max-width` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)が利用出来ます。そして子要素の横幅が親要素に依存していることから、親要素の横幅を表す相対単位である[パーセンテージ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)を用いると良いことがわかります。

以上より、修正したコードは次のようになります。質問文のコードに変数 `molfArray` が含まれていなかったため、このコードでは簡単なテストデータを入れた変数 `molfArray` を定義しています。

```js
const molfArray = [
  "https://placehold.jp/ff0000/ffffff/1000x1000.png?text=1",
  "https://placehold.jp/00ff00/ffffff/1000x1000.png?text=2",
];

let imageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
let molfQuestionName = molfArray[imageNumber];
let questionElement = document.getElementById("question-molf-name");
questionElement.innerText = molfQuestionName;

// 正解のモルフを用意する。

let imageElement = document.getElementById("left");
let imageMolf = '<img src="' + molfQuestionName + '.jpg">';
// imageElement.innerHTML = imageMolf;

// 不正解のモルフを用意する。

do {
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
} while (i === imageNumber);
let notImageNumber = i;
let notImageElement = document.getElementById("right");
let notImageMolf = '<img src="' + molfArray[notImageNumber] + '.jpg">';
// notImageElement.innerHTML = notImageMolf;

// 正解と不正解を格納した配列を用意する。

let optionArray = [];
optionArray[0] = imageMolf;
optionArray[1] = notImageMolf;

// 正解と不正解をランダムにエレメントに格納する。

c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
do {
  d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
} while (c === d);

a = c;
b = d;

imageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[a];
notImageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[b];
```

```css
.flex {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.flex div {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%; /* 追加 */
}
```

```html
<div id="question-molf-name"></div>
<div class="flex">
  <div id="left">aaa</div>
  <div id="right">aaa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 素早いご対応ありがとうございます！

> div 要素 (#left, #right) へ横幅を指定していても、その子要素にあたる img 要素には横幅の制約は適用されません。
> つまり、 img 要素に対して横幅の制約を加えることでこの問題を解決することが出来ます。

なるほど。
divタグの中に要素が直接あるわけではなく（ex.テキスト）、imgタグが入っていて小要素になっているのに、divタグへCSSを適用していたのがミス。
と認識しました。

勉強になります、ありがとうございます！！

Comment: @yknst さん> その認識で間違っていないと思います。また質問内容とは直接関係ありませんが、もし問題が解決した場合は、[質問を解決済みにして](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/32986)いただけると助かります。

Comment: 失礼しました。ただいま解決済に設定いたしました。ありがとうございました！